# 3-part YA book about nuclear war in the UK - any ideas?

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

This book affected me so much I couldn't read the third story the first time I borrowed it from the library. Went back to it from curiosity when I was about 13.

It's called something like 'The Tomorrow Children' but I can't find it ammongst the more recent or more famous other works/media etc that has the same name.

Any ideas? It's three-part device was well structured, with the stories moving from a place near Manchester when the first bombs are dropped, and then the 2nd part is about the immediate aftermath.  3rd part is mutants.

Comment: [Children of the Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dust_(novel))?

Comment: When were you 13?

Comment: Oh dear god, I was 13 in 1991... :/

Comment: And WOW it was Children of the Dust, thank you sir, I hope you have a ROCKING day!

Comment: @SakinaMurdock Don't forget to 'accept' Richard's answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - She ain't comin' back :-(

Answer (score 4):

This is "[Children of the Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dust_(novel))". Note that this was a stand-alone novel in three sections and not a trilogy:

> Children of the Dust is a post-apocalyptic, dystopian novel, written
>   by Louise Lawrence, published in 1985. The book details three
>   generations of a family during the aftermath of a nuclear war. The
>   survivors of the blast suffer through radiation, nuclear winter, feuds
>   between rival groups and radiation-induced mutations, eventually
>   evolving into a new species, Homo superior. The new species has
>   adapted to the loss of the ozone layer and the abundant radiation, and
>   will become the dominant species on the planet.
>
> The book contains three sections, one for each generation. The novel
>   offers some hope that humanity could survive the horrors of war (as an
>   allegory for the current age) in order to form a new world.